# Executing sql in rails migration opens to sql injection attacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, migration, sql-injection

So I just read on multiple sources that passing dynamic data using SQL opens the database to SQL Injection attacks:

I have a rails migration which inserts data into a join table as:

```
class MovePlayerToJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    games = Game.all
    games.each do |g|
      g.players.each do |p|
        execute "insert into games_players (player_id, game_id) values (#{p}, #{g.id})"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how the above opens me to SQL injection attacks since it's a one time task and I would be passing values through strong parameters after this as they will have to go through my controllers. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: What is `g.players` right now? Something using `serialize` (i.e. a blob of YAML inside the database)? A PostgreSQL `int[]` column? Something else?

Comment: @muistooshort sorry for the late response. It is a `serialized` array

Comment: Ugh, `serialize` complicates things so Sean Huber's answer is the right way to go. I'd also recommend adding foreign key constraints inside the database to your new join table so that you'll know that `player_id` and `game_id` are valid IDs; you'd probably want to do that *before* migrating the data so that you can clean up any broken data that `serialize` left behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is not likely to be at risk of sql injection. Regardless, it is good practice in Rails to sanitize raw sql fragements: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html

Example:

```
class MovePlayerToJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    games = Game.all
    games.each do |g|
      g.players.each do |p|
        query = sanitize_sql_array(['insert into games_players (player_id, game_id) values (?, ?)', p.id, g.id])
        connection.execute(query)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting an undefined method `sanitize_sql`

Comment: Sorry the method is actually named `sanitize_sql_array`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_array. I've updated the answer. You may need to include `ActiveRecord::Sanitization::ClassMethods` also.

Comment: You could also use `connection.quote` in the migration.